# Using two lithium-ion batteries to power three separate components with buck converters

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, buck, lithium-ion, l298

I'm trying to use two 7.4 V two lihtium-ion bateries connected in series to power an Arduino Due, a Buslinker, and two L298N motor drivers.

In series, the total voltage would be 14.8 V.

The 14.8 V will go into a power block splitter which will split this voltage to be used for three buck converters.

The buck converters will be used as follows:

- Buck1 to Arduino: 14.8 V -> 12 V
- Buck2 to BusLinker: 14.8 V -> 7.4 V
- Buck3 to two L298N motor driver: 14.8 V -> 12 V

After calculating the total voltage after the buck converters, it will be 31.4 V.

***First question:* My total voltage input from the two lithium-ion batteries in series is 14.8V and my voltage being used is 31.4V. Can this configuration be used to operate it successfully or would I need to add two more lithium-ion batteries in series to make the input voltage 29.6V?

*Has been answered:* The total voltage consumption does not matter. In this case, the total current is what matters. Therefore, it seems that I could run everything on a single 7.4V 50C 2S Li-ion battery, since it can provide 260 amperes.

***Second question:*** Am I wiring everything correctly in my schematic?

***Third question:*** Is this a voltage issue? Is there not enough voltage to power two servo motors?

*Has been answered:* Indeed, it was due to the desktop power supply. The constant current was set to 3.3A. Once I set it to 4.5A, the two servo motors and the Arduino were able to run perfectly using the same 7.4V and shared GND.

***Fourth question:*** The BusLinker board states that the voltage input ranges from 5-14V, but each servo motor requires 7.4V. Is it okay to supply 14V to the BusLinker board? Will the board regulate it to 7.4V for each servo motor connected?

**TESTING PERFORMED**

***During individual testing, this is what I did:***

- I used 7.4V from my power supply to provide power to the LewsanSoul Buslinker, which was connected to two servo motors. (Note that each motor requires 7.4V each.)
- I used a 9V battery to power the Arduino.
- The Buslink and the Arduino were connected as needed for the Tx pin, GND pin, etc.

**Results:**
Each of the servo motors moved, but it would move sporadically. It was as if it was intermittently working.

When I disconnected one servo motor and just tested one servo motor, it worked well.

Also, when I looked at my power supply that was providing power to the servo motors, each time I moved the motors, it showed that the voltage dropped significantly. It dropped to ~2v.

Details:

- Li-ion battery:7.4V 2S 50C 5200mAh  [Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B092CZGW2P)
- Arduino Due: 7-12V                [Link](https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-due)
- Buslinker: 5-14V                  [Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073XY5NT1)
- L298N: 12V                        [Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BK1QL5T)

**EDIT 1:**

1. Total current = 6.1A
2. Question for revising schematic: If I revise the schematic, then would it be okay to connect one 7.4V 2S 50C lithium-ion battery in parallel with one Arduino, two L298N motor drivers, and one Buslinker? In this case, will each load receive 7.4V and use the amount of current that it needs?

**EDIT 2:**

Updated Schematic to include GND

GND from Arduino pin is shared with (-)BUCK 2 and (-)BUCK 3

[image: Schematic Rev2]

**EDIT 3:**

I redesigned the schematic. The circuit is being powered by one lithium-ion battery with no buck converters.

Let me know if this redesign is correct.

[image: Redsigned Schematic]

**EDIT 3.1:**

After reading some comments, it seems like the second schematic would be my best choice.

1. The buck converter won't be needed for the Arduino since the power that will supply the "vin" input will be stepped down to 5V.
2. The buck converter for the LewsanSoul BusLinker won't be needed since it only requires 7.4V and the 7.4V lithium-ion battery can provide it. Also, the 50C 2S lithium-ion battery can provide enough current to power each servo motor.
3. The buck converter won't be needed for the DC motor. I can run it on 7.4V. I don't need the DC motor to spin at the full 200 RPM.

Comment: Total voltage is meaningless. You want to calculate total current

Comment: Going based off of the provided info from the spec sheets and how much current each component uses, I get a total of roughly 6.1A.

Comment: For the Arduino to control "everything", use a common GND.  Please state in the question: Why not supply all loads with 7.4 V (or 11 V) - seems in range for each. Why separate converters from battery to 12 V? The 14.8 V of a 4S pack of 3.7 V cells is *nominal*, to get typical capacity (5.2 Ah), a typical cut-off voltage would be 3 V per cell: 12 V. This is too low to operate a buck converter to 12 V, 5S would do nicely. OTOH, I don't see any of your loads needing an exact voltage. With a load of 6.1 A *continuous*, expect the pack(s) to last for about 40 minutes, less when old or in frost.

Comment: @greybeard The reason I didn't want to use just one 7.4V LiPo battery to supply voltage to all loads is because I wanted to supply the Arduino with its max voltage (which is 12V), and the four DC motors with its max voltage (which is 12V). Also, I'm fairly new to this as well. So I didn't think that one 7.4V LiPo battery was enough. Now that I see that current is more important rather than voltage, I may reconsider my original idea. I assume that one 50C 2S LiPo battery can provide all the current that is needed while running all the loads with 7.4V.

Comment: @greybeard "Continue from last comment".... Going with your idea and running everything from one 7.4v 2S LiPo battery, I can see that the buck converters can be removed as they won't be needed anymore. To answer your question, "Why separate converters from battery to 12 V? ". Now that I look at the schematic some more, you are right. In my schematic, I could just use one Buck converter for the two 12V loads.

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for clarification or complementing information: [Edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/655527/edit) your post. The motors would be almost the same speed at 11.1 V, and slightly less than three quarters at the cut-off voltage - about 9 V. There is an annoying voltage drop in drivers as antiquated as the L298.

Comment: It’s not obvious from your schematic what shares ground and what does not. Please update it.

Comment: There is no point in feeding 12 volts to the Arduino - the 12 volts will just be stepped down to 5 or 3.3 volts by a voltage regulator, wasting power.

Answer (score 2):

With common GND, adding up supply voltages is pointless.
At different voltages, the most useful measure is added up *power*: voltage * current.

In the schematic, the only GND connection depicted is from Arduino to BLE module.
You write about more ground connections during tests, you probably are OK there, but the schematic is incomplete - I don't think it confusing.

Power supply voltage drops during tests are easily explained by the power supply not being in a position to cope with instantaneous demand. (With a (desk/lab) supply, this may be as simple as not increasing the current limit when going from one load to two.)
Unstable power supply easily explains erratic behaviour.

I don't see any "power" inductors on neither *bus link* nor *debug* board:
I expect neither to provide reduced supply voltage.

The voltage spec for the servo seems to be stated with an error, the same torques a claimed in the user manual for 7.4 V and **6** V, respectively - this is the range of voltages from many a "2S Lithium battery" from nominal to cut-off.

The one reason I see to use a voltage "higher than 2S" is the motors being too slow:

- use a contemporary motor driver
- use a motor specified for the speed needed at intended load and cut-off voltage/6 V - with a bit of room to spare

Answer (score 0):

> My total voltage input from the two Li-ion batteries in series is 14.8V and my voltage being used is 31.4V,

That's meaningless.

That's like saying "the total of your height (170 cm) and my height (160 cm) is 330 cm". That's meaning less. You're not standing on my head. As we are all standing on the ground, our height do not add up.

As all the voltages are referenced to the same ground, the voltages do not add up.